# Long Input in an editable field

Tags: website-design, gui-design

In my web app I have an input field that is editable by click and the author is unable to view the full title if it is too long.

A good example is the Title field of "Ask Question" in this site.
If you insert a long title the end of it is not visible.

Considering that in my app there is no overview mode where I can show the title in full length, what is a good UX way to show the user the title without overview mode?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you call overview mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your question but I think the two options are:

1. wrap the text on multiple lines by using a multi-line input field
2. truncate the text if it's longer than a maximum size and add a signifier for that. I have seen the three dots (...) used a lot.